# Rearranging a table of data in various ranges

Tags: excel

I have a data of some failures and their occurrences. I would like to group these data according to ranges in the occurrences. `EG. >500  Wheel alignment, dpf muffler assy`
The range will be in 10s. `EG. >=500, 490-500, 480-490.`

Sorry i hadnt mentioned earlier, I am using excel 2007 to do this!!! :(((

```
Failures                                 Occurences
WHEEL ALIGNMENT  (ADJ)                   588
DPF MUFFLER ASSY (R/SERVICE/I)           557
ADJUST ALL BRAKES (ADJ)                  436
V-BELT(ALTERNATOR/FAN/COMPRESSOR) (R/I)  402
BATTERY (R/I)                            380
FRT BRAKE SHOE & LINING ASSY (R/I)       375
ELECTRICAL REPAIR                        270
CLUTCH OVERHAUL                          252
STVE & GBL SERVICE PACKAGE               247
```

Comment: Why not group by `occurrences/10` ?

Comment: There's not much to go on here. You could try `Group By floor(Occurrences/10)` as part of your query.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You should've mentioned that it's Excel from the beginning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and populate a ranges table (to be flexible in changing ranges if you need to)

```
CREATE TABLE failure_ranges (range_start INT, range_end INT);
```

Then you can use a query like this (a version for **MySql**)

```
SELECT CONCAT(r.range_start, '-', r.range_end) `range`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.failures ORDER BY f.occurences DESC) failures
  FROM failures f JOIN failure_ranges r
    ON f.occurences BETWEEN r.range_start AND r.range_end
 GROUP BY r.range_start, r.range_end
```

Sample output:

```
|   RANGE |                                              FAILURES |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 241-250 |                            STVE & GBL SERVICE PACKAGE |
| 251-260 |                                       CLUTCH OVERHAUL |
| 261-270 |                                     ELECTRICAL REPAIR |
| 371-380 |      BATTERY (R/I),FRT BRAKE SHOE & LINING ASSY (R/I) |
| 401-410 |               V-BELT(ALTERNATOR/FAN/COMPRESSOR) (R/I) |
| 431-440 |                               ADJUST ALL BRAKES (ADJ) |
| 500-999 | WHEEL ALIGNMENT  (ADJ),DPF MUFFLER ASSY (R/SERVICE/I) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3547/4)** demo (**MySql**)

Comment: @poahsincheah While the question was incorrectly tagged, as it now stands, this isn't an appropriate answer